# Break lines in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I've tried to use XSL to output the liste of the customer in a XML file but there is no break lines between values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output 
  method="html"
  encoding="ISO-8859-1"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
  indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//client"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//client">
     <xsl:value-of select="./nom/." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is

```
DoeNampelluro
```

Normallly I want to get

```
Doe
Nam
Pelluro
```

I've let indent="yes" but that does not do the job

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**First of all, the provided XSLT code is quite strange**:

```
<xsl:template match="//client">
  <xsl:value-of select="./nom/." />
</xsl:template>
```

**This is much better written as the equivalent**:

```
<xsl:template match="client">
 <xsl:value-of select="nom" />
</xsl:template>
```

**And the way to output multi-line text is... well, to use the new-line character:**

```
<xsl:template match="client">
 <xsl:value-of select="nom" />
 <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="client">
  <xsl:value-of select="nom" />
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <client>
   <nom>A</nom>
 </client>
 <client>
   <nom>B</nom>
 </client>
 <client>
   <nom>C</nom>
 </client>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
A
B
C
```

**In case you want to produce xHtml output (not just text), then instead of the NL character, a `<br>` element has to be produced**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="client">
  <xsl:value-of select="nom" />
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
    <br />
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Now, the output is**:

```
A<br/>B<br/>C
```

**and it displays in the browser as**:

A
B
C

Answer (score 2):

just add: `<br/>` tag.
it work for me .

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each select="allowedValueList/allowed">
**<br/>**<xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

does the trick.